# Sorted Linked List position

Tags: c, linked-list

I started learning about linked lists and I am having a problem with insertion at the right position in ascending or descending order. Maybe I haven't understood it right. Could you please help me understand the procedure here.

```
void insert(int x) {
Node* temp = (Node*) malloc(sizeof(Node));
Node* prev = NULL;
Node* curr = head;

if(head!= NULL){
    prev = curr;
    while(prev != NULL){
        prev = prev->next;
    }

    if(prev->data > x){
        temp->data = x;
        temp->next=head;
        head=temp;
    }else{
        temp->data = x;
        temp->next = NULL;
        prev->next = temp;
    }

}else{
    head = temp;
}
}
```

Comment: Well, first off, when you are iterating over the list, your code looks like it goes to the end of the list. From your problem statement, it sounds like you want to "insert at the right position", so you should iterate to the insertion point or until you hit the end of the list.

Comment: `prev` will always be `NULL` after the `while` loop, leading to a probable crash.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a lot of bugs. I think its better to add my version of code rather than pointing out bugs in your code. Here is my code.

```
void insert(int x)
{
    Node* temp = (Node*) malloc(sizeof(Node));
    temp->data = x;
    temp->next = NULL;
    Node* curr=head;
    if(curr==NULL)//if this were the first element...
    {
        head = temp;
        return;
    }
    if(curr->data > x)
    //special case:
    //adding element at the head itself.
    //you need to change the head pointer then.
    {
        temp->next = curr;
        head = temp;
        return;
    }
    while(curr->next!=NULL)
    {
        if(curr->next->data > x)
        {
            temp->next = curr->next;
            curr->next  =temp;
            return;
        }
        curr = curr->next;
    }
    if(curr->next==NULL)
    //adding the element at the end...
    {
        curr->next = temp;
        return;
    }
}
```